# Django: how to call "contains" function in a template?

Tags: python, django, contains

I need to know how to use `contains` in a Django template.

I want to do something like this:

In view:

```
my_query = MyClass.objects.filter(key=value).my_var
```

And in a template like:

```
{% if my_query contains 'X' %}
    <p>My var contains an X</p>
{% endif %}
{% if my_query contains 'Y' %}
    <p>My var contains a Y</p>
{% endif %}
```

Other way I already know would be by validating in view:

```
my_query_X = MyClass.objects.filter(my_var__contains='X').exists()
my_query_Y = MyClass.objects.filter(my_var__contains='Y').exists()
```

Then in template:

```
{% if my_query_x == True %}
    <p>My var contains an X</p>
{% endif %}
{% if my_query_y == True %}
    <p>My var contains a Y</p>
{% endif %}
```

But I don't want to use this last option since it would take more queries to do in view.

Comment: It's much better to do it in Python using .exists() because then _the database_ can do the check, instead of building a whole list, sending it to a template and checking there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `in`:

```
{% if 'X' in my_query %}
    <p>My var contains an X</p>
{% endif %}
{% if 'Y' in my_query %}
    <p>My var contains a Y</p>
{% endif %}
```